# form processing asp.net mvc 2 or 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to make a website that will be one form at first page. So user get on that website and they can fill my form.

After I login as Admin to see that forms in grid that users filled.

Just to have overview of forms when I log as Admin.

p.s gusts on site, don't need to be any users. They are filling that Form.

So what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: This is super vague. If you just want people to fill out a form, chances are you could even get by just using a service like surveymonkey. Otherwise, if you feel you need to write this yourself I recommend just starting to learn ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: hi...I made form in asp.net mvc 2 and I send results to a grid. My main problem is to see that grid just when I log as admin. Only I need to se that grid with filled forms

Comment: if that is the case, you should probably ask a more specific question about that. What you probably need to look into are forms authentication, the AuthorizeAttribute and possibly action filters.

Comment: It seems you're trying to implement Google Forms all over again... http://docs.google.com, choose "Create New..."/"Form" in the upper left corner.

Comment: but I want to do that in asp-net mvc ...why? becase I'll update that form, and add more link on website later ..tnx

Answer (score 0):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1

This is the MusicStore tutorial on Microsoft's dedicated .net site.  It will walk you through MVC3, creating data models and storing them in a database.

If you want the MVC2 demo (which since MVC3 can run both MVC2 and MVC3 applications on the MVC3 dlls, I'd advise just using MVC3) you can get it through the archives on the site.

This sample code will also walk you through how to display data from the database on an EF query.

Also, for security sakes, you can use [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] and the provided SQL Server Role Provider.

To create the database tables to accommodate the Sql Server Role Provider you can check out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx

If you have specific questions on how to use this technology please let me know!

Comment: Ok, I know for that example. I pass my forms data to a grid (where I can see, print or download my Forms data)...now I just need to pass that grid - that I as Admin could only see that ...thank you

Comment: That's where the SqlServerRole Provider comes into play.  Your Authorize annotations can limit access to a Url if it is explicitly typed and you can control navigation to the page that will show you your forms using the Identity.IsInRole(...)

I posted the link for how to setup a SqlServerRoleProvider database, which gives you your security that can restrict to a given security role or user.  If you have any specific questions please let me know.